# How to detect if the keycode_numpad_dot is clicked in Android?

Tags: android, keycode

I'm a newbie on this language. I am struggling on this problem detecting if the keycode_numpad_dot is clicked.

Comment: You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

For numpad dot use:

```
KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL
```

Sample code:

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL)

    return true;

    else return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Android Key Code:

key 83    NUMPAD_DOT

Comment: Unresolved reference: VK_DECIMAL